# wc -l to count lines all txt files in folders and subfolders

Tags: osx, bsd, wc

I have a few hundred txt files in several subfolders and I would like the count the lines in each txt file. I can do this for all txt files in the current directory by using:

```
for f in *.txt; do wc -l "$f"; done
```

which outputs:

```
[number] [txt filename]
[number] [txt filename]
[number] [txt filename]
```

Which is good. However, I don't want to to do this hundreds of times, navigating to each subfolder. The directory structure is:

```
-main
    -folder1
        textfile1.txt
        textfile2.txt
        textfile3.txt
    -folder2
        textfile4.txt
        textfile5.txt
        textfile6.txt
    -folder3
        textfile7.txt
        textfile8.txt
        textfile9.txt
...and so forth
```

Of note, the text files contain spaces and several dots before the .txt extension. Using the wc -l up above as written didn't produce any errors, though. Using terminal on a Mac running MacOS, which behaves like BSD for the most part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /the/path/to/search/ -name "*.txt" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Comment: do also note the `+` variation of `{}`, which would allow for fewer calls to `wc` (as `wc` can accept multiple filenames)

Comment: Jeff, I didn't know that about + vs {}. Thanks for the tip. one of the things Apple got right is compiling everything in 64-bit, so the CLI tools tend to be able to handle a lot. Or, at least I think that's how that stuff works!

Answer (score 2):

If the directory structure is constant, then wildcards can safely expand the list (assuming there aren't so many resulting files that you exceed the command line length):

```
wc -l main/*/*.txt
```

or

```
wc -l */*/*.txt
```

... depending on where you're starting from and what you want to include.

Answer (score -1):

```
find /yourpath -type f -name "*.txt" -exec wc -l {} /dev/null \;
```

Comment: There's not really a need to use /dev/null here; perhaps you picked it up from some `grep` examples?